# L3 equivalent to ifcase

Tags: latex3, xparse

Consider the custom code of date showing the month and year only:

```
\def\shccustomdate{%
 \ifcase \month \or January\or February\or March\or April\or May\or June\or
   July\or August\or September\or October\or November\or December\fi,\space
 \number\year}
```

What would be an equivalent `xparse` solution?

I found the `\if_case:w` primitive but do not know how to use it.

This is my attempt at it:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\shccustomdate}{}
 {
    \if_case:w \int_eval:n { \c_sys_month_int }
    \or: January
    \or: February
    \or: March
    \or: April
    \or: May
    \or: June
    \or: July
    \or: August
    \or: September
    \or: October
    \or: November
    \or: December
    \fi: ,~ 
    \int_eval:n { \c_sys_year_int }
 }
```

Is this correctly implemented or are there better  ways?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the primitive `\if_case:w` as you did, yes, but a correct-er way would be to use `\int_case:nn`.  Here's an implementation with a clear separation of document-level and code-level interfaces, and some syntactic sugar to change the date format:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{nth}
\ExplSyntaxOn

% Document level
\NewDocumentCommand \shccustomdate { } { \shc_date: }
\NewDocumentCommand \shcdateformat { m } { \shc_set_date_format:n {#1} }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand \monthname { m } { \shc_month_name:n {#1} }

% Code level
\cs_new_protected:Npn \shc_date:
  {
    \__shc_print_date:xxx
      { \int_use:N \c_sys_day_int }
      { \int_use:N \c_sys_month_int }
      { \int_use:N \c_sys_year_int }
  }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \shc_set_date_format:n #1
  { \cs_set_protected:Npn \__shc_print_date:nnn ##1 ##2 ##3 {#1} }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__shc_print_date:nnn { xxx }
\cs_new:Npn \shc_month_name:n #1
  {
    \int_case:nn {#1}
      {
        {  1 } { January }
        {  2 } { February }
        {  3 } { March }
        {  4 } { April }
        {  5 } { May }
        {  6 } { June }
        {  7 } { July }
        {  8 } { August }
        {  9 } { September }
        { 10 } { October }
        { 11 } { November }
        { 12 } { December }
      }
  }

% Default format
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__shc_print_date:nnn #1 #2 #3 { \monthname{#2},~#3 }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\verb|\shcdateformat{\monthname{#2}, #3}|:

\shccustomdate

\bigskip

\verb|\shcdateformat{\monthname{#2} \nth{#1}, #3}|:
\shcdateformat{\monthname{#2} \nth{#1}, #3}

\shccustomdate

\end{document}
```

The code above has two parts.  The first one sets the date format with `\shc_set_date_format:n`.  That function basically defines:

```latex
\cs_new_protected:Npn \__shc_print_date:nnn #1 #2 #3
  { <format> }
```

where `<format>` is the argument to `\shcdateformat`, and in that argument `#1` is the day, `#2` is the month, and `#3` is the year.

Then the second part, in `\shc_date:`, expands `\c_sys_day_int`, `\c_sys_month_int` (the month is further expanded to its name using `\int_case:nn`) and `\c_sys_year_int`, and passes them as arguments to `\__shc_print_date:nnn` which does the typesetting.

Comment: This is amazing. Got a bit lost but will read it to understand.

Comment: @azetina I added some explanation on the working of the code. If there's anything you don't understand, feel free to ask! :)

Comment: Thanks. Am trying to see through the code and understand that you are using the days, months and year. But where is `\__shc_print_date:xxx` defined? I guess am failing to understand the construct of `\cs_new_protected:Npn`.

Comment: @azetina `\__shc_print_date:xxx` is actually `\__shc_print_date:nnn`, but it `x`-expands the arguments before passing them to the underlying macro. `\__shc_print_date:xxx` is called a “variant” of the `:nnn` version, and it's defined in the `\cs_generate_variant:Nn` line.  Take a look at section *4 Expansion Control* of [`expl3.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/expl3.pdf).

Comment: Will do my best to read about it. Thanks a lot. This is so interesting. You surely make it seem easy. One last comment: with `\shcdateformat` you can control the order of the date format, right?

Comment: @azetina Yeah, the expansion control in `expl3` makes it a lot easier to define function-like macros.  Yes, in `\shcdateformat`, `#1` is always the day, `#2` is the month, and `#3` is the year, so `\shcdateformat{#3-#2-#1}` is `yyyy-mm-dd`, and `\shcdateformat{#1-#2-#3}` is `dd-mm-yyyy`. Also, I changed the answer a bit to separate the month name, in case you need it as a number.

Answer (score 3):

I'd use `\clist_item:Nn` with a constant clist.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\shccustomdate}{O{english}}
 {
  \azetina_date_monthname:n { #1 }
  \azetina_date_separator:n { #1 }
  \azetina_year:
 }

\clist_const:Nn \c_azetina_date_months_english_clist
 {
  January,February,March,April,May,June,July,
  August,September,October,November,December
 }
\tl_const:Nn \c_azetina_date_separator_english_tl { ,\nobreakspace }

\clist_const:Nn \c_azetina_date_months_italian_clist
 {
  gennaio,febbraio,marzo,aprile,maggio,giugno,luglio,
  agosto,settembre,ottobre,novembre,dicembre
 }
\clist_const:Nn \c_azetina_date_separator_italian_tl { \nobreakspace }

\cs_new:Nn \azetina_date_monthname:n
 {
  \clist_item:cn { c_azetina_date_months_#1_clist } { \c_sys_month_int }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \azetina_date_separator:n
 {
  \tl_use:c { c_azetina_date_separator_#1_tl }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \azetina_year:
 {
  \int_to_arabic:n { \c_sys_year_int }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\shccustomdate

\shccustomdate[italian]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without multilingual support, this would boil down to

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\shccustomdate}{}
 {
  \clist_item:Nn \c_azetina_date_monthname_clist { \c_sys_month_int }
  ,\nobreakspace
  \int_to_arabic:n { \c_sys_year_int }
 }
\clist_const:Nn \c_azetina_date_monthname_clist
 {
  January,February,March,April,May,June,July,
  August,September,October,November,December
 }
```

Unless the user tampers with `\c_sys_month_int`, this is safe enough, because the constant will *necessarily* evaluate to an integer in the required range [1–12].

---

Here is support for different formats to be chosen at runtime.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{nth}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\shccustomdate}{}
 {
  \azetina_date_custom:nnn { \c_sys_year_int } { \c_sys_month_int } { \c_sys_day_int }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\shcsetformat}{m}
 {
  \cs_set:Nn \azetina_date_custom:nnn { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\decimal}{m}
 {
  \int_to_arabic:n { #1 }
 }
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\monthname}{m}
 {
  \clist_item:Nn \c_azetina_date_monthname_clist { #1 }
 }

\clist_const:Nn \c_azetina_date_monthname_clist
 {
  January,February,March,April,May,June,July,
  August,September,October,November,December
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

% initialize
\shcsetformat{\monthname{#2},~\decimal{#1}}

\begin{document}

\shccustomdate

\shcsetformat{\monthname{#2}~\nth{#3}, \decimal{#1}}

\shccustomdate

\end{document}
```

[image]

In `\shcsetformat`, `#1` refers to the year, `#2` to the month and `#3` to the day, according to ISO conventions. Note that, as the setting of the format is done outside `\ExplSyntaxOn`-`\ExplSyntaxOff`, the tie `~` means “no-break space”.

Comment: I like this implementation as well. `\int_to_arabic` evaluates the constants, right? `\shcsetformat{\monthname{#2},~\decimal{#1}}` only uses month and year and leaves empty the day, right?

Comment: @azetina `\int_to_arabic:n` is essentially the same as `\int_eval:n`, but more semantic for the use case. The macro you mention *ignores* the day.

Comment: One more question Can you tell me where I can find the definition of `\nobreakspace`?

Comment: @azetina It is the equivalent of the standard tie `~`; clearly, we cannot use `~` in the expl3 programming environment for a non breaking space.